# Adding a header to a XML message in Synapse

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

Using Synapse 2.1, I am trying to transform an XML message with no header into a SOAP message with a header containing credentials to consume a web service. Something like this:

Synapse incoming message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   ...TAGS...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Synapse outgoing message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <yta:Authentication>
      <yta:UserName>srnm</yta:UserName>
      <yta:Password>psswrd</yta:Password>
   </yta:Authentication>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   ...TAGS...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How could I configure Synapse to do it? I am successfully using a transform file to update the body of the message, but not to add a header to the output.

I tried using the header and property mediators in the configuration file, but I am not sure what is the way to go. Reading about the header mediator it says "At the moment set header only supports simple valued headers". Could this be the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, I ended up using a script mediator with an inline javascript script in the configuration file using the addHeader method. See below:

```
<script language="js">
   <![CDATA[
     var user = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::UserName.toString();
     var psswd = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::Password.toString();
     mc.addHeader(false, <yta:Authentication xmlns:yta="yta:namespace url"><yta:UserName>{user}</yta:UserName><yta:Password>{psswd}</yta:Password></yta:Authentication>);
   ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT mediator to manipulate it. So add an XSLT transformation with required headers and it would add required headers. Or use Script mediator / Class mediator where you can manipulate message.

Please refer followings which will be useful.

http://wso2.org/forum/thread/10794

http://wso2.org/forum/thread/10843

If this xml structure is not needed.
you can use Http Headers you can use properties as below.
http://blog.thilinamb.com/2011/04/how-to-access-web-service-using-http.html

Comment: Thank you, Shelan. I actually tried adding it to the XSLT transformation, but it didn't work. So, now I am thinking that the web service requires to send the credentials in the HTTP header. Is that possible to do it with any of the existing mediators (thinking of header or property)?

Comment: What is the problem you got with XSLT? did you give the source "." as mentioned in the forum post?. This is not name value pairs but a hierarchical structure. Other option is to use a class mediator to construct the message. There you have the full access. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java

Comment: When I used the XSLT approach, I got an error "No operation named Envelope existed in the web service" from the web service provider, so I understand that it takes Envelope from "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" as the operation and authenticating in the web service as anonymous user. I will look into using a class mediator as you suggest. I was looking at inline scripts like Groovy or JavaScript. Would you think it will be easy to create that header using any of those?

Comment: Yes it is possible with script mediators. (Here how you can access Envelope. or even simple name value pair headers) http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Script+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to secure the service. The easiest then, is to use username-token security. Go to the services dashboard in WSO2 ESB for your proxy service and secure it, using UT. Also see http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+200%3A+Using+WS-Security+with+policy+attachments+for+proxy+services for a security sample

Comment: Thank you Samisa. I spent some time at security policies as you suggested and it got quite complicated in no time. I spent some time at WS-Security and Rampart configuration but it got me nowhere. I am sure this is one option to go, but having no security knowledge it would be a very time consuming proposition. In the end I used a script in the Synapse configuration (see answer entry.)